# Table populated by Service SelectionListener

Tags: oracle, listener, selection, oracle-adf

I am struggling getting a working selectionListener on a Read-Only Table populated by a Service (exposed in the DataControls). No Entity / VO / ApplicationModule involved. I use ADF 11.1.1.5

**my jsff**:

```
<af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
    <f:facet name="center">
      <af:table value="#{bindings.DocumentMetadatenDTO.collectionModel}"
                var="row" rows="#{bindings.DocumentMetadatenDTO.rangeSize}"
                emptyText="Empty"
                fetchSize="#{bindings.DocumentMetadatenDTO.rangeSize}"
                rowBandingInterval="0"
                rowSelection="single" id="t1"
                selectionListener="#{pageFlowScope.documentSearchBean.documentTableSelectionListener}"
                partialTriggers="::psl1">
```

**my pageFlowScoped Bean**:

```
public void documentTableSelectionListener(SelectionEvent selectionEvent) {
    RichTable table = (RichTable) selectionEvent.getSource();
    Object selection = table.getSelectedRowData(); // **returns null**
}
```

**my bindings definition**:

```
<executables>
<methodIterator Binds="getDocuments.result"
  DataControl="DocumentSearchServiceMock" RangeSize="-1"
  BeanClass="****.model.DocumentMetadatenDTO"
  id="getDocumentsIterator"/>
 </executables>
 <bindings>
<methodAction id="getDocuments" RequiresUpdateModel="true"
              Action="invokeMethod" MethodName="getDocuments"
              IsViewObjectMethod="false"
              DataControl="DocumentSearchServiceMock"
              InstanceName="DocumentSearchServiceMock.dataProvider"
              ReturnName="data.DocumentSearchServiceMock.methodResults.getDocuments_DocumentSearchServiceMock_dataProvider_getDocuments_result">
  <NamedData NDName="query"
             NDValue="#{pageFlowScope.documentSearchBean.documentSearchQuery}"
             NDType="****.model.DocumentSearchQuery"/>
</methodAction>
<tree IterBinding="getDocumentsIterator" id="DocumentMetadatenDTO">
  <nodeDefinition DefName="****.model.DocumentMetadatenDTO"
                  Name="DocumentMetadatenDTO0">
    <AttrNames>
      <Item Value="id"/>
      <Item Value="creationDate"/>
      <Item Value="zielArchive"/>
      <Item Value="documentType"/>
      <Item Value="documentSource"/>
    </AttrNames>
  </nodeDefinition>
</tree>
<attributeValues IterBinding="getDocumentsIterator" id="id">
  <AttrNames>
    <Item Value="id"/>
  </AttrNames>
</attributeValues>
</bindings>
```

Does anybody have any idea?

PS: I already tried to update the iterator current row using [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/23-generic-table-selection-listener-169162.pdf) example from Oracle, and then selecting an attribute value from the bindings, without success neither.

Answer (score 0):

Your scopes are messed up. 
References to components on the page (such as the table) shouldn't be in a pageFlowScope bean.

Comment: Hi Shay, Thanks a lot for your feedback. But the scope of the bean doesn't have anything to do here, or? The same issue occurs if the bean is request scoped for instance. Why would it be so bad to have the References to components in a PageFlow scoped bean btw?